# Android: Only part of GLSurfaceView drawn when resuming from recent apps list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, glsurfaceview

Odd problem.  If I:

- Launch my app so the splashscreen is showing, then.....
- immediately 'minimise' it  and send it to the 'recent apps' list, then....
- quickly resume the app from the 'recent apps' list, before the splashscreen goes away
- watch the splashscreen and wait while resources finish loading

Then when the splashscreen disappears, only the part of the GLSurfaceView that was in the small version of the app view while it was in the recent apps list is actually visible.

I'll explain by way of (very basic) graphics :-).......

**I'd like to know if there are any tools I can use to find out what this blank rectangle is.**

[image]

So I basically have a layout to which I ad my views.

**Code snippets**

```
 layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
 layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

I then add my GLSurfaceView (MyGLView) and my splashscreen (which is a standard View) once it's been created:

```
 layout.addView(myGLView);
 layout.addView(splashscreen);  //The work behind the splashscreen takes place on an AsyncTask
```

Once the AsyncTask has finished it's work, it removes the Splashscreen from the layout to reveal the GLSurfaceView underneath:

```
 layout.removeView(splashscreen);
```

Note that if we then place it back to the recent apps list as shown in fig 5 above, then the **maximise** it again, all is back to normal and I can see everything.  Likewise, if I just launch the app and leave it running, all is OK as well as virtually every other sitatuation I can think of.  It's only when dong things the way shown above that the problem manifests itself.

What am I doing wrong?  Would appreciate any helpful comments.

Please ask if anymore information is required.

***Test Device* : Google Nexus 10**

***OS*             : Stock Lollipop 5.0.1**

**Edit:**

Thanks to @fadden's suggestion below, I've managed to get some new information.  When running **adb tools dumpsys window** when the app is *correctly* displayed, I get the following:

```
mFocusedApp=AppWindowToken{b68cbca token=Token{dc7b35 ActivityRecord{7dae96c0 com.me.myapp/.MainActivity t1761}}}
```

However, with the app *not displaying correctly*, I get this:

```
mFocusedApp=AppWindowToken{28ecfffa token=Token{189d2225 ActivityRecord{38b161u0 com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity t1110}}}
```

**Having said the above**, if I tap the screen and run *dumpsys window* again, the mFocusedApp does change to my app (but the problem doesn't go away) and I have seen similar behavour (with the *dumpsys window* output with other apps downloaded from the Play Store but their graphics don't have this problem, so this may not be relevant at all.

I have confirmed my view (myGLView has focus via DDMS).

Comment: Not sure but might be related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12629/workaround-to-losing-the-opengl-context-when-android-pauses

Comment: Hi @MorrisonChang, this is a different problem.  It's not the GLContext, besides, I'm retaining the GLContrext in my app.

Comment: Other suggestion: have you tried on different devices / OS versions (just in case this is a driver problem / OS level problem)

Comment: Well, I did try it on an old Ginerbread device, but the recent apps list doesn't work in the same way on that so the problem wasn't evident,  however, there are plenty of apps that I've downloaded form the Play Store that works OK on this (Nexus 10) so it must be something I'm doing...

Comment: Sounds like either the GLSurfaceView rendering is being clipped, or the Surface is being obscured by other windows.  You could try poking at it with hierarchyviewer or `adb shell dumpsys window` to see what else is on screen.  If you were using a plain SurfaceView (which *does* work with GLES) you could try setting the Z order to put it on top and see if it still gets clipped, but I'm not sure how well that works with GLSurfaceView (which has all the thread wrappers and other gunk).

Comment: Thanks @fadden, you're right, I used your dumpsys suggestion and indeed it looks as though the 'recents' activity is the 'focused app' when this happens, and my app at other times! - Any ideas how to proceed?  Thanks again!!

Comment: For anyone who comes across this problem, it appears it may be a bug in the Lollipop recent apps feature , it didn't happen <= Kit Kat and I've downloaded so far, 3 apps from the Play Store that exhibit the same behaviour.  Also, prior to discovering these other appsm I had been working for the last 24 hours to resolve the issue and have been unable to do so.

Comment: Did you end up figuring out how to avoid this issue? I'm able to undo this issue by changing the phone orientation, but other techniques I have tried (such as redrawing all views) do not work.

Comment: Hi @Michael, unfortunately not, I've tried everything, but the issues still persists to this day.